# How to get the status of previous command in fish script

Tags: fish

Say I want to do something in multi commands in a fish script:

```
do_some_important_things

if /* previous command succeeds*/
   echo Good
else
   echo Failed
end
```

I'm not sure how to write the `/* previous command succeeds*/` part. I tried `$status`, but it give me an warning:

> fish: Variables may not be used as commands. Instead, define a function like 'function status; 0 $argv; end' or use the eval builtin instead, like 'eval $status'. See the help section for the function command by typing 'help function'.
>   /Users/freewind/Downloads/bbb/m (line 50): if $status

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`test`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#test) command and the [`status`](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#variables-special) variable:

```
if test $status -eq 0
```

Comment: Though in simple cases you can directly do `if do_some_important_things`

Comment: Yes, that would be the preferred method.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very common use case, so there is a command to achieve this easily: `and`.

Assume you want to call `foo` and afterwards, if and only if it succeeded (exit status equals 0) you want to call `bar`. Then you can simply write

```
foo; and bar
```