# Fish Shell: Conditional execution based on $status?

Tags: fish

In the fish shell the syntax for conditionals is hard to find. Does anyone have a link to an explanation of how to write an if, with ands and ors?

In particular I would like to write

```
if not $status
  do a command
end
```

To do a command when the previous command returned a non-success. How do I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the status of previous command in fish script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34721446/how-to-get-the-status-of-previous-command-in-fish-script)

Comment: Not a dup. The question is not how to get status but how to best dispatch to code based on the status.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See http://fishshell.com/docs/current/commands.html#if and http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_conditionals.

Fish's if structure looks like this:

```
if COMMAND
   # do something if it succeeded
else
   # do something if it failed ($status != 0)
end
```

Then there are also the `not`, `and` and `or` commands, that you can use like

```
if not COMMAND1; or COMMAND2
    # and so on
```

If you really want to test a variable (e.g. $status), you need to use `test` as the command, like

```
if test $status -eq 0
```

Do keep in mind that $status changes after every command, so if you need to use the status of an earlier command (common in prompts) you need to do what Joachim Pileborg said, save it to another variable.

Also, `test` has some issues with quotes (because it's one of the few parts of fish to adhere to POSIX) - if in `test $foo -eq 0` $foo is undefined, test will error out, and if it is undefined in `test -n $foo`, the test will be true (because POSIX demands that test with one argument be true).

---

As a sidenote, in fish versions before 2.3.0, you need to add `begin` and `end` around a condition with `and` or `or` because it was interpreted weirdly.

So you'd have to do

if begin COMMAND; or COMMAND2; end
      # do something for status = 0

Answer (score 2):

The shortest short form would be

```
the_previous_command; or do_a_command
# ..................^^^^^
```

Assuming you get your `$status` from "the_previous_command"

Answer (score 1):

I use the status variable to display it on the prompt if it's non-zero. For that I use the following function:

```
function __pileon_status_prompt
        set -l __status $status
        if test $__status != 0
                printf '[%s%s%s]' (set_color red) $__status (set_color normal)
        end
end
```

As you can see I set a local variable to the value of `$status` and the check that variable in the condition.

Comment: Thanks. Is that the "recommended" way to do it?